# rtweet package: auth_setup_default() does not work

Tags: r, rtweet

when I run search_tweets function, I got:

Error in `default_cached_auth()`:
! No default authentication found. Please call `auth_setup_default()`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

So I run auth_setup_default(), and I got:

Error in httr::init_oauth1.0(endpoint, app, permission = permission, is_interactive = is_interactive,  :
Bad Request (HTTP 400).

This happened just after I upgraded R and R studio. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you seen this issue already reported on their github site: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/756

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. That's the same problem as I have. I am still waiting for the approval of my app. So I guess I have to wait then.

Comment: Sorry, I introduced a bug in the last release, install it like explained in the linked issue: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/756#issuecomment-1401069647 `install.packages("rtweet", repos = 'https://ropensci.r-universe.dev/')`